# jQuery Slice Function / Each Pair of Two

Tags: jquery, function, slice, each

I am trying to loop through a series of elements, iterating a number and applying it in different ways to pairs of two.

So, say I have twenty elements, and want to leave the first 6 elements untouched, I slice at 6. Then, I need to apply styles to each of those elements starting at #7, but need to do so in pairs of two. So, elements 7 & 8 will be top: 0; left: 0; while elements 9 & 10 will be top: 240px; left: 240px;

Elements 11 & 12 will then be top: 480px; left: 0; while elements 13 & 14 will be top: 720px; left: 240px;

I hope that pattern makes sense.

I do not know the best way to achieve this. My code is below, however, I only refer to the elements using 'this' and in no way am trying to identify pairs. That is what I do not understand how to do.

Here is my example:

```
$('#main article').slice(6).each(function(i) {

    // first pair of two
    $(this).css({
        top  : i * 240 + 'px'
    });

    // second pair of two
    $(this).css({
        top  : i * 240 + 'px',
        left : 480 + 'px'
    });

});
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS only non-incremental update below original JS answer.**

You could change it to use a for loop on the list and increment the index partway through:

```
var el = $('#main .article');
for(var i=0; i <= el.length; i++){
    var left = (i == 0) ? 0 : i * 40;
        $(el[i]).css({
            top: i * 40 + "px",
            left: left + "px"
        });
        i++;
        $(el[i]).css({
            top: i * 40 + "px",
            left: left + "px"
        });
}​
```

Of course you can still use the slice, but you'll need to position those first 6 elements correctly if you are using position:relative or absolute so that they don't overlap each other.

[Here's a fiddle showing it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/mSfRS/4/)

### Edited from comment discussion below:

If the incremental values aren't important to you you can achieve the pattern with straight CSS:

```
.article:nth-child(4n-1),
.article:nth-child(4n-1) + li{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle for that.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/vRBUZ/1/)

Comment: Hey Doug, I appreciate the response, but again, this seems to be selecting every other element rather than every other pair of 2 elements. I took another approach that, ultimately, failed. I was hoping I could do this: http://pastie.org/4605089 but that did nothing. I can use this approach: http://pastie.org/4605095 but that only really works with applying something like an opacity, not for what I am trying to do which is increment a value and apply it to the top or left properties. I really need to find a good solution to this.

Comment: In the fiddle it's not working for you? This is what I see in the fiddle: http://i.imgur.com/ircrI.png. It's incremental every other element, or every pair. Maybe I'm just not understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine, it did not seem to work in my code however. To make this easy, what would you say is the simplest way of selecting pairs using jQuery? Pretend we don't have to increment anything, and just apply opacity: 1; to the first pair and opacity: 0.4; to the second pair. How would we pull this off?

Comment: You can do the same as the code above. All the for loop is doing is going through the list of elements and saying "do this on element 0. increase index to 1. do this on element 1. repeat loop.".

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery you can do it just with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/vRBUZ/1/. I will append the answer as well.

Comment: Also, if it's not working for you on your page, be sure to change the selector from the class to the tag that you used. I just realized that you aren't using article as a classname selector, but as the tag selector.

Comment: I will experiment more with your code when I get home tonight. Using CSS isn't an option, as I ultimately need to be able to increment a value and add it as a top / left property, which you cannot do in CSS (which is too bad, because we do have the counter-increment property, it just only works when coupled with the content property). I'm not much of a javascript guy, I do as much as I can in CSS, and am pretty well versed with it. Thanks for the help, I will let you know if I was successful using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do - there is just a bit of code that you need in your .each loop:

```
var pair = 0;
$('#main .article').slice(6).each(function(i) {
    var second = i%2 > 0;
    var topPx = (20 + (pair * 24)) + 'px';
    var leftPx = (pair * 24 + (second? 20 : 0)) + 'px';
    $(this).css({ "top": topPx, "left": leftPx });
    if(second) pair++;
});
```

This uses the mod operator to see if the item is the 2nd one of the pair, and will base the top position on that pair value. The left position gets adjusted slightly so it can be seen. I adjusted the number of pixels to fit the jsFiddle view.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/w3NsP/5/).

Comment: Is there a way to do it with pure selectors?

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to be grabbing pairs of 2 for me. I should mention my markup is slightly different, as I am using an article tag and not a div with the class of article, but regardless, using your code I can apply styles to every other element, rather than every other pair of 2 elements (although, in your Fiddle, it seems to work properly...). To simply things, I altered to the code to change the opacity of the elements, which is easier for identifying what the code is doing in terms of selecting elements. Here is my example: http://pastie.org/4604759